# Open nuke software through chrome?

Tags: nuke

How to open a desktop application(like Nuke) through browser.

for example: RV software have a url protocol. we can use that (rvlink://).

Comment: Unless it has a URI scheme associated with it, you can’t do that.

Comment: i'm using rv software. they have a external link to lanch that software through browser.

https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219042088-RVLink-URLs-RV-as-protocol-handler

Comment: Could you tell me "what for" you need to open NUKE through browser?

Comment: @Andy The most obvious application I can think of is to open scripts from web-based UIs aimed to browse assets or track production. Sorry for intercepting your question (Badri can obviously have a different motivation) but I'd be interested in solutions too, for the reason above.
If anyone knows of any existing ones, please share, otherwise I could try figure out some workarounds, as soon as I have some spare time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-Launching-applications-using-custom-browser-protocols

---

Note that this is asking your operating system to "launch the thing registered with the requested custom browser protocol". Similarly you can have a hyperlink `mailto:///` which opens the email application registered on the users computer. `rvlink:///` is registered by RV as one of these custom browser protocols during it's installation.

If you want more control you would need a process running on the user's machine that you interact with. For example that's the approach shotgun's competitor ftrack took leveraging a local process they call ftrack connect (http://ftrack-connect.rtd.ftrack.com/en/0.1.17/developing/tutorial/custom_applications.html)

If you want to run something completely custom you could take a look at running your own [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). You would initiate the registered RPC command from the web application. Check out http://www.zerorpc.io/ or https://crossbar.io/ for some more information.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I spotted in an earlier response of yours that you're using Shotgun and it's launch in RV features. In which case - are you aware of Shotgun Toolkit?

https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219039788-Toolkit-Home-Page

It provides app launching via the website, which it accomplishes via Shotgun desktop (a desktop app). It used to work via a browser method that chrome etc moved away from so now requires the desktop app hook.

There's actually a huge amount that SGTK does, though I think you might be able to disable everything except the app launching if you wanted. We've got it implemented across 4 locations here and it's pretty decent.